# If I have a visitor visa for Switzerland (Schengen visa), can I visit France?

Tags: visas, france, schengen, switzerland

I'm an Indian citizen and I have got a UK visitor visa.  I hope to travel to France for 4 days, however we were not able to get an appointment. So now we are planning to get a visa for Switzerland (Schengen visa), and visit France. Is it permissible to visit France and not Switzerland on the Schengen visa?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You're more likely to get response if the question is clearly worded. I've tidied it up and made it more legible, please let me know if I've made a mistake and changed the meaning of your text.

Comment: and the answer is Yes.

Comment: @RudyGunawan But isn't Switzerland not Schengen?

Comment: @drN Switzerland is in the Schengen area (for the time being, at least) even though it is not in the EU. Note that you will need a credible story about your need to go to Switzerland to get the visa. If you have no intention to go to Switzerland and just want to circumvent long waiting times at the French consulate, the Swiss consulate should refuse to process your application.

Comment: @Annoyed Interesting! Did not know that.